# Why is this CAML Query is not filtering results from SharePoint Web Service call?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2007, caml

I am trying to filter the list of results returned by the following web service call to a SharePoint list.  When I have

```
query.InnerText = "";
```

the results include every row in the SharePoint list - including rows having an IN SERVICE DATE less than today, greater than today, or no value at all.  I need the CAML query to filter, but adding the Where statement does not work.

```
service.Url = url;
String pipeProjectSummaryListGuid = "{2D193799-F1FB-46B1-A313-56B8B12E1111}";

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
String rowLimit = "9000";

query.InnerText = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name=\"In_x0020_Service_x0020_Date\" /><Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Today /></Value></Gt></Where>";
viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"NEW_ID\" /><FieldRef Name=\"In_x0020_Service_x0020_Date\" /><FieldRef Name=\"ProjectPriority\" />";
queryOptions.InnerXml = "<ViewAttributes Scope=\"Recursive\" /><IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>";

try
{
    results = service.GetListItems(pipeProjectSummaryListGuid, null, query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `query.InnerXml` instead of `query.InnerText`.

Comment: query.InnnerXml did the trick.  I swear I had tried that...Does SharePoint Web Services cache results?